# Struggling with Jquery Masonry alignment

Tags: php, jquery, alignment, jquery-masonry

I keep struggling with masonry. It seems it is trying to do it's work, but it's not aligning properly. I have been trying to fix it for hours now. I searched here and found people with the same problem, but the solutions didn't work for me. Here is all the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <?php while (next_news()): ?>
<div class="newsitem">
<span class="newstitle"><?php printNewsTitleLink(); ?></span>
<span class="newsdate"><?php printNewsDate(); ?></span>
<span class="newscontent"><?php printNewsContent(); ?></span>
</div>    
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
div.newsitem {
    width:215px;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:5px;
    padding:15px;
    float: left;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#container {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's the script, I did try to give the columns a width or change the Gutterwidth, but nothing worked:

My Script:-

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#container').masonry({
itemSelector: '.newsitem'
});
});
</script>
```

And here the included files to make it all work:

```
<script src="<?php echo $_zp_themeroot; ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $_zp_themeroot; ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

And where it should be working: http://dagloos.com/lust/index.php?p=news
Please help me, I would really appreciate it. I'm about to pull out my hair over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was!

```
<script src="<?php echo $_zp_themeroot; ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

Just had to be placed AFTER the fancy box script.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try putting

```
  $(function(){$('#container').masonry({ itemSelector: '.newsitem' }); });
```

inside the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

function, it should work then I think.

---

Shot in the dark but try and replace:

```
div.newsitem {}
```

with

```
.newsitem{}
```

Sidenote:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lust/themes/bottomline/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
```

currently leads to a 404.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I changed the script and CSS, but sadly it didn't fix it. About the side note, thanks for noticing, I removed the code since it wasn't using it anymore.

Comment: I fixed it! (see answer) I guess the codes were in conflict or something. Thanks for looking in on it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the console, its clearly says that it couldn't load masonry.

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'

Comment: Is it still giving the error now? What is this console you're talking about? Sounds handy

Comment: Now its fine. [Check How to open console's in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)